# In devc++, why only numbers can be input, but summation cannot be performed.?

Tags: c

title：Ask the user to enter a string of integers and any number of spaces, and finally sum the numbers：

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sum=0,ch;
    printf ("Please enter an integer of any length and the number of spaces：");  
    scanf ("%d",&ch); 

    while(ch!='13')
    {
        if(ch!='32') sum=sum+ch;
    }
    printf ("sum=%d\n",sum);
     
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run according to the following code, I can only input, but cannot calculate the sum of the final sum.

Comment: Your while is an infinite loop

Comment: `while(ch!='13')` That loop is either empty or infinite, since `ch` does not change inside the loop.

Comment: `'13'` should be `13`, because `ch` is  `int`(`%d`)

Comment: In addition to the other comments: you probably want `'13'` -> `13` and `'32'` -> `32`. But anyway your code doesn't make much sense and I don't understand what the program is supposed to do. Please [edit] and show an example of input and expected output. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Instead of `'13'` use `'\n'` (or `10`) or `'\r'` (or `13`); instead of `'32'` use `' '` (or `32`). `'13'` is a multi-character literal: something you really shouldn't be using ([C11 6.4.4.4p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10): *[using multi-character literals] is implementation defined*).

Comment: So you want the input to be e.g: `1    3 5  10` and the output `19`?

Answer (score 0):

`'13'` is not a valid character If you want to have some special codesC has special escape sequences:

[image]

So for line feed (13 in decimal) use `'\n'`

BTW characters are just simple integers. If you want to compare the char variable with the number simple `if(ch!=32)`. Note that `'32'` is not a valid character.

Comment: I think we didn't want pictures of text ;-)

Comment: It is picture of picture. I do not think anyone will copy paste 3 characters . And that is the reason why when we post code, we do not post pictures. Here it is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally wrong and anyway you can't do this with `scanf`.

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Please enter integers separated by space and press Enter: ");

  char string[100];                        // maximum string length is 100
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);    // read the whole string from the user

  int sum = 0;
  char* pch = strtok(string, " ");  // read strtok documentation for more information

  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", pch);          // print the number (remove this, it's just for illustration)
    sum += atoi(pch);             // convert string to number and add to sum
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");      // get next number
  }

  printf("Sum = %d", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Read the documentation of [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for more information.